# Как вывести московское время на сайте?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно только с помощью jquery вывести на сайте московское время, а не локальное? И можно ли в принципе? Спасибо.

Comment: Так какой ответ правильный?:) А то время в ответах разное)

Comment: после изменения ответа автором  - показывает правильно теперь :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var moskowUtc = 3;
var timerId = setInterval(function() {
  let t = new Date(),
    tt = t.getUTCHours() + moskowUtc;
  document.getElementById('tik-tak').innerHTML = (tt > 24 ? "0" : "") + (tt > 24 ? tt - 24 : tt) + ":" + (t.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + t.getMinutes() + ":" + (t.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0' : '') + t.getSeconds();
  document.getElementById('tik-tak').classList.add("step");
}, 1000);
```

```css
.step {
  display: inline-block;
  animation-name: fadeit;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes fadeit {
  from {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="tik-tak"></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `toLocaleTimeString` + передайте `timeZone`:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var currentTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('ru-RU', { timeZone: 'Europe/Moscow' });
  document.getElementById('currentTime').innerHTML = currentTime;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="currentTime"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function () {
  let date = new Date();
  let time = `${date.getUTCHours() + 3}:${date.getUTCMinutes()}:${date.getUTCSeconds()}`;
  console.log(time);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]